# How to use a variable as the socket server ip address

Tags: python, serversocket, python-sockets

So I would like to have a variable as the socket server ip address... I have some issues. I get the issue with `server.bind(ADDR)`

```
import socket
import requests
import threading

def controller(conn, addr):
    connected = True
    while connected:
        msg_length = conn.recv(HEADER).decode(FORMAT)
        msg_length = int(msg_length)
        msg = conn.recv(msg_length).decode(FORMAT)
        if msg == DISCONNET:
            connected = False

        print(f'{msg}')

def start():
    print('Server: Server Started')
    server.listen()
    while True:
        conn, addr = server.accept()
        thread = threading.Thread(target = controller, args = (conn, adrr))
        thread.start()

host_name = socket.gethostname()    
prip = socket.gethostbyname(host_name)
puip = requests.get('https://api.ipify.org').text

HEADER = 128
PORT = 5050
SERVER = puip
ADDR = (SERVER, PORT)
FORMAT = 'utf-8'
DISCONNET = '!DISCONNECT'

server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server.bind(ADDR)

start()
```

Error Message:

```
server.bind((SERVER, PORT))
OSError: [WinError 10049] The requested address is not valid in its context
```

Comment: What gives you `print(puip)` and `print(type(puip))` after the `request.get` call? If you just want to have a socket to `api.ipify.org` then use `SERVER = 'api.ipify.org'`

Comment: i am trying to get the public ip of the device and then use it as the server ip address. I have tried `SERVER = 'api.ipify.org'` but still get the same error

Comment: when you get the public ip of the device, how can you connect to it? Are behind a router in a local network and have a local ip address?

Comment: O i thought we could connect to it with out doing something specila

Comment: could you tell me on how to do this

Comment: If you are in a local network and your app is running on the device and wants to connect to itself, you should use `'localhost'` as the address

Comment: how about people from another network

Comment: I think first you should check your implementation whether you can connect within the same network. If that works, you can try to connect between networks. You need the public ip (as you did) but there need to be open ports in the routers, port forwardings etc. That's about network configurations.

Comment: o ok i do on the same network, and i have to open the ports... but what if another player wants to make the server... they would have to open the port then

Comment: is the 80 port good

Comment: many ports are good as long as the router / firewall is configured to let it through. Many routers have a default configuration that they let port 80 out (=web traffic) bot not in. In that case you need to open port 80 for incoming traffic on port 80 and then implement a port forwarding rule (tp the device you want to connect to).

Comment: ya i have changed my port to port 80. As the server address on my side be my ipv4 or public one. And the on the Client side do they need to use my ipv4 or my public

Comment: wait i know how to do it i think... i just need to open up a port

Comment: if the connection is between local networks and via the internet, then you need to use public ips. And the router/firewall on the server side needs open port and port forwarding